# How to make a ConstantList Class in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, constants

How to make a ConstantList class in Objective C of an application which could be accessible to all the classes who are using constants.

like in Actionscript we do:

```
public class ConstantList
{
   public static const EVENT_CHANGE:String = "event_change";
}
```

Or what is the best approach to handle application constant.

Regards
Ranjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global constants, like the following:

```
//MyConstants.m    
NSString * const EVENT_CHANGE = @"event_change";

// MyConstants.h
extern NSString* const EVENT_CHANGE;
```

Now include `MyConstants.h` header to your implementation file and you can use EVENT_CHANGE constant string in it

Comment: Thanks Vladimir.

I am getting this error: "expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'extern' "

Comment: I suspect you didn't `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` at the top of your own header file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Vladimir's approach.

Just for completeness: You can do it as a class like this:

```
@interface Constants : NSObject {
}
+ (NSString*)aConstantString;
@end

@implementation Constants
+ (NSString*)aConstantString {
    return @"This is always the same and accessible from everywhere";
}
@end
```

You access the value like:

```
NSString* string = [Constants aConstantString];
```